# Return common elements appear one or multiple times in a list of list

Tags: python, list, functional-programming

```
list_of_list=[[1,2,3,4,133,90],[4,11,22,99,3],[5,3,22,66,12,10],[1,99,101]]
```

the code should return elements that can be common with one or multiple sublists.

> output: [1,3,4,22,99]

###### what I have tried from stack overflow:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
c = [3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12]
elements_in_all = list(set.union(*map(set, [a, b, c])))
elements_in_all
```

###### why it's not solving my case:

doing mapping and set intersection which only picks common elements if the elements appeared in all sublists.

But in my case, the element can be common in one single sublist or in all sublists.

Can anyone suggest a pythonic way to solve this problem?

Comment: What does "common in one single sublist" mean?

Comment: Why doesn't your result for `list_of_lists` include 22?

Comment: sorry, I included 22. it was a typo.."common in one single sublist" means the elements repetition happens in just another single sublist instead of repeating in all sublists

Comment: What is your desired output, given the input above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c = collections.Counter()
for sub in list_of_list:
    c.update(set(sub))
```

this creates a mapping `element => number of sublists`, from which you can pick whatever you want, for example:

```
[v for v, cnt in c.items() if cnt > 1]
```

to make a list of elements that occur in at least two lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
import collections

list_of_lists = [[1,2,3,4,133,90],[4,11,22,99,3],[5,3,22,66,12,10],[1,99,101]]

# Get the combinations which have a repeating element
repeating = [element for element in itertools.product(*list_of_lists) 
             if len(set(element)) != len(list_of_lists)]


# Take only the elements which appear more than once
more_than_once = []

for element in repeating:
    more_than_once.append([item for item, count in 
                           collections.Counter(element).items() if count > 1])


# Get uniques
uniques = set()

for m in more_than_once:
    for item in m:
        uniques.add(item)

unique_list = list(uniques)
```

unique_list = [1, 3, 4, 22, 99]

Answer (score -1):

Here's a version closer in sprit to your posted code:

```
list(set.union(*[a.intersection(b) 
     for a, b in itertools.combinations(map(set, list_of_list), 2)]))
```